# Why is Android / IE using 3DES when AES is available?

Tags: security, ssl, web-server, tls

I have a Zimbra installation and want to harden the cipher suites. I disabled some and am quite OK with what is left.

The problem now is that the [Qualys SSL tes](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)t shows a lot of clients will use 3DES, which is only left available as last fallback by me.

If I look at the supported ciphers of Android 5 and my server (for example), there is more overlap and the same AES cipher suite is available at both.

Why is that AES cipher not used?

Here is the whole test output:
[image: ssl test output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically each client has their own preference in which ciphers they support.

To stick with your example: [Android 5.0.0](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Android&version=5.0.0) supports a reasonable number but has some odd preferences, with some objectively weaker ciphers preferred over some stronger ones.

According to the SSL Labs scan (the *"Cipher Suites (sorted by strength; the server has no preference)"* section) your server will only support a limited number of ciphers and does not display a preference, leaving the cipher negotiation primarily to the client, which results in `TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa)`

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is determined by the cipher list passed from the client to the server, where the client tells the server what ciphers it supports, and which priority each of those ciphers has.  [Android, in particular, has made some insecure choices about the preference order of its cipher suites](http://op-co.de/blog/posts/android_ssl_downgrade/), preferring very insecure ciphers over secure ones that it supports, without giving any explanation as to why.

My suspicion is that it's a design choice. By choosing a less computationally intensive cipher, you use less power and therefore get more battery life, which is something consumers notice and care about in a smartphone, and in contrast, when it comes to security, as long as the end user sees that lock icon, "it's secure," and that's all they care about (if they even care that much).

So, they're using 3DES because they have a higher preference for that weaker cipher, and you allow it to be used.  The only way to stop it from being picked by a client with dubious preferences is to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue already explained by @HBrujin and @HopelessN00b, you can set a preferred list cipher for the webserver, who can also have preferences, not only the client. I recommend to use the settings elaborated by the [Bettercrypto.org](https://bettercrypto.org/) project [*Applied Crypto Hardening*](https://bettercrypto.org/static/applied-crypto-hardening.pdf).

E.g. for Apache, you can use

```
SSLCipherSuite 'EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!ECDSA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA'
```

in your settings for SSL/TLS. To support 3DES, remove `3DES` from the string, but only if it is really necessary and you need to support software from the last century. This cipherstring can be used in business environments with old software (which is not recommended either, but business, you know...).

Comment: The problem is Zimbra doesn't have a setting for that. I modified it in the Jetty settings, but that is not upgrade safe. Also, I think I have to look into the postfix settings too.

Comment: Questions on administration software like Zimbra are off-topic here. In the linked paper you can also find settings for Postfix and many others.